# Creating full permision user in mysql over ssh connection

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add a new user to a MySQL db.
The user should get all rights and should connect over TCP/IP ssh connection.

I have used the following commands:

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

This didn't do the trick so I looked on SO where I found a question like this with an answer telling to make the same user again but with '%' instead of 'localhost'. I've tried this, but I am still getting the same error.

Does anyone have an idea?

EDIT:

The error I am receiving is this one:

Could not connect the SSH Tunnel

```
Authentication error. Please check that your username and password are
correct and try again. Details(Original exception message):
Authentication failed, please check credentials.Please refer to
logs for details.
```

Comment: What 'error' are you getting? You forgot to mention HOW exactly its failing.

Comment: `%` is for network-based connections of any kind, even over SSH. `localhost` is for UNIX socket-based ones only.

Comment: @tadman, if the user will ssh into the box, then they would be acting from `localhost` though, right?

Comment: @JNevill In MySQL terms "localhost" means "via local UNIX socket" and is completely different from the same connection via TCP/IP. That is if you're connecting over `/tmp/mysql.sock` or equivalent then you're considered "localhost", otherwise network-based.

Comment: Voting to close since it's unclear what the problem is. @MathiasKiekens, please update with your actual error message or explanation of the problem you are having when you attempt a connection otherwise we can't help.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay(was the end of my work day and had a bussy evening. I've edited the question

Comment: I might have forgot to mention that I am trying to connect to a db on my own machine(vagrant)